# Associative array not filling up in server-sent-event environement

Tags: javascript, arrays, server-sent-events

I think I'm on the wrong track here:

I have an event source that gives me updates on the underlying system oprations. The page is intended to show said events in a jquery powered treetable. I receieve the events perfectly but I realized that there were a case I did not handle, the case where an event arrives but is missing it's parent. In this case I need to fetch the missing root plus all potentially missing children of that root node from the database. This works fine too.

```
//init fct
//...
eventSource.addEventListener("new_node", onEventSourceNewNodeEvent);
//...

function onEventSourceNewNodeEvent(event) {
    let data = event.data;
    if (!data)
        return;

    let rows = $(data).filter("tr");
    rows.each(function (index, row) {
        let parentEventId = row.getAttribute("data-tt-parent-id");
        let parentNode = _table.treetable("node", parentEventId);

        // if headless state is not fully
        // resolved yet keep adding new rows to array
        if (headlessRows[parentEventId]) {
            headlessRows[parentEventId].push(row);
            return;
        } else if (parentEventId && !parentNode) { // headless state found
            if (!headlessRows[parentEventId])
                headlessRows[parentEventId] = [];

            headlessRows[parentEventId].push(row);
            fetchMissingNodes(parentEventId);
            return;
        }

        insertNode(row, parentNode);
    });
}

function fetchMissingNodes(parentEventId) {
    let url = _table.data("url") + parentEventId;

    $.get(url, function (data, textStatus, request) {
        if (!data)
            return;

        let rows = $(data).filter("tr");

        //insert root and children into table
        _table.treetable("loadBranch", null, rows);

        let parentNode = _table.treetable("node", parentEventId);
        let lastLoadedRow = $(rows.last());

        let headlessRowsArray = headlessRows[parentEventId];
        while (headlessRowsArray && headlessRowsArray.length > 0) {
            let row = headlessRowsArray.shift();
            let rowId = row.getAttribute("data-tt-id");
            if (rowId <= lastLoadedRow) // already loaded event from previous fetch
                continue;

            insertNode(row, parentNode);

            let pendingUpdatesArray = pendingUpdates[rowId];
            // shouldn't be more than one but who know future versions
            while (pendingUpdatesArray && pendingUpdatesArray.length > 0) {
                let updateEvent = headlessRowsArray.shift();
                updateNode(updateEvent)
            }
            delete pendingUpdates[rowId]; // <- something better here?
        }
        delete headlessRows[parentEventId]; // <- something better here too?

    });
}
```

The problem is around the line `if (headlessRows[parentEventId])`. 
When I run it step by step (putting a debugger instruction just before) everything works fine, the headless array is created and filled correctly. 
But as soon as I let it run full speed everything breaks. 
The logs I printed seems to indicate that the array is not behaving in the way I was expecting it to. If I print the array with a console.log it shows as follow :

```
(2957754) [empty × 2957754]
    length : 2957754
    __proto__ : Array(0)
```

It seems to be missing any actual data. whereas it shows as follow when I execute it step by step:

```
(2957748) [empty × 2957747, Array(1)]
    2957747:[tr.node.UNDETERMINED]
    length:2957748
    __proto__:Array(0)
```

I'm missing something but it is still eluding me.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. You're reading the data before it's populated. When you run it in the debugger, it has time to populate. Just a guess.

Comment: But I thought JS was single threaded and as such that race condition were impossible. Does SSE introduce a risk of race condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is async, you do http request but you treat him as synchronized code.
try this fix

```js
//init fct
//...
eventSource.addEventListener("new_node", onEventSourceNewNodeEvent);
//...

async function onEventSourceNewNodeEvent(event) {
    let data = event.data;
    if (!data)
        return;

    let rows = $(data).filter("tr");
    rows.each(function (index, row) {
        let parentEventId = row.getAttribute("data-tt-parent-id");
        let parentNode = _table.treetable("node", parentEventId);

        // if headless state is not fully
        // resolved yet keep adding new rows to array
        if (headlessRows[parentEventId]) {
            headlessRows[parentEventId].push(row);
            return;
        } else if (parentEventId && !parentNode) { // headless state found
            if (!headlessRows[parentEventId])
                headlessRows[parentEventId] = [];

            headlessRows[parentEventId].push(row);
            await fetchMissingNodes(parentEventId);
            return;
        }

        insertNode(row, parentNode);
    });
}

function fetchMissingNodes(parentEventId) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
       let url = _table.data("url") + parentEventId;

      $.get(url, function (data, textStatus, request) {
          if (!data){
              resolve()
              return;
          }
              

          let rows = $(data).filter("tr");

          //insert root and children into table
          _table.treetable("loadBranch", null, rows);

          let parentNode = _table.treetable("node", parentEventId);
          let lastLoadedRow = $(rows.last());

          let headlessRowsArray = headlessRows[parentEventId];
          while (headlessRowsArray && headlessRowsArray.length > 0) {
              let row = headlessRowsArray.shift();
              let rowId = row.getAttribute("data-tt-id");
              if (rowId <= lastLoadedRow) // already loaded event from previous fetch
                  continue;

              insertNode(row, parentNode);

              let pendingUpdatesArray = pendingUpdates[rowId];
              // shouldn't be more than one but who know future versions
              while (pendingUpdatesArray && pendingUpdatesArray.length > 0) {
                  let updateEvent = headlessRowsArray.shift();
                  updateNode(updateEvent)
              }
              delete pendingUpdates[rowId]; // <- something better here?
          }
          delete headlessRows[parentEventId]; // <- something better here too?
           resolve()
      });
    })
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this keyword. But you placed it at the wrong spot, it needs to be on the  `rows.each(function...` part. I feel it is the right direction but even this way the problem persist, I believe because of that foreach actually

Comment: rows each is synchronized  . fetchMissingNodes is asynchronous.  puting a promise in the fetchMissingNodes  and the do a wait in the loop will make your loop work liked it synchronized. have you try to run it?

Comment: if I put async on function onEventSourceNewNodeEvent the script doesn't even start `await is only valid in async functions`. I'll try putting it on both function declaration

Comment: I think the main problem comes from the fact that all server sent event arrive calls `onEventSourceNewNodeEvent`. If I could force the events to be queued instead. I start to think also that my idea of an associative array to store the headless nodes that might arrive while I'm fetching the root is fondamentally flawed

Comment: Validated the answer because even though it didn't fix my specific problem (it came from a misunderstanding of JS's event stack) it is still relevant